# script to send email with attachments

Tags: shell-script, email

I have the file like below

**filelist.txt**

```
C:\Users\project\files\target1.txt;
C:\Users\project\files\target2.txt;
C:\Users\project\files\target3.txt;
C:\Users\project\files\target4.txt;
```

Now, the script should read this filelist.txt and send email with target1, target2,target3 and target4 as attachments and with email body as below

**Email body:**

```
Hi Team,

please find the target files attached

thanks,
ABC
```

Comment: Those look like Windows files, but this is the Unix.SE.

Comment: what `mail` command are you using ?  some of them have a `--attach` option.

Comment: There are lots of answers to this already on unix.stackexchange.com. Please see this [Google site search](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Aunix.stackexchange.com+send+email+with+attachment) for some of them. A keyword that may be useful is MIME